Terminology and notation for maps between topological vector spaces that vanish at $0$ "faster than linearly"
I am interested in learning what terminology and notation, other than the small-$o$ notation, exist in the literature for describing the maps $U\to\mathbf{R}$, where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbf{R}$, that vanish at $0$ "faster than linearly."
Using the small-$o$ notation, a function $f\colon U\to\mathbf{R}$ has this property if and only if $f(x) = o(x)$ as $x\to 0$.
The terminology I am looking for should also be applicable to maps $\mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf{R}^n$, and preferably to maps between any topological vector spaces.
Usually, in the case of such maps between normed vector spaces, they are described in terms of $o(\Vert\boldsymbol{v}\Vert)$ as $\boldsymbol{v}\to\mathbf{0}$.
However, the choice of the norm here is irrelevant, as long as the topology is defined.
I find that this kind of maps plays a fundamental role in basic analysis and in basic differential geometry, so describing them in terms of $o(\Vert\boldsymbol{v}\Vert)$ seems awkward, especially because in the finite-dimensional case the choice of the norm is completely irrelevant.
Also, the small-$o$ notation cannot be directly used to qualify a map $f$: one needs to write something like "$f(\boldsymbol{v}) = o(\Vert\boldsymbol{v}\Vert)$ as $\boldsymbol{v}\to\mathbf{0}$", introducing a fresh variable $\boldsymbol{v}$.
Of course, a map $f$ has this property if an only if $f(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ and $f'(\mathbf{0})$ is the null operator.
However, I wish to be able to define and discuss these maps before/without defining differentiation.
By the way, I suspect that the definition of this class of maps can be generalized to be meaningful for maps between any topological groups.
This class of maps is closely related to an equivalence relation on maps between affine spaces (or differentiable manifolds) at a given point, according to which two maps are equivalent if at the given point their values coincide and the difference of the associated linear maps between the tangent spaces is vanishing at $0$ faster than linearly.
(In terms of jets this means they have the same $1$-jet.)
I've seen a few terms for this equivalence relation.
Such maps of affine spaces may be said

to be tangent to each other at the given point (Deudonné),
to have contact of order $\ge 1$ at the given point (Bourbaki),
to have the same $1$-jet at the given point (see jet bundle).


See here.

@jd27, thanks, i've already seen the terms like tangent to $0$ map at $0$ (Deudonné, Lang). Elsewhere Lang writes "tangent to $0$", not at. I should mention this in the question probably. I've also seen terms like having contact of order $\ge 1$ with $0$ map (Bourbaki). I am not quite satisfied with those terms. In particular because they are really about an equivalence relation between functions.
